# How to refresh a view in Django

Tags: django

I'm fairly new to Django and couldn't figure this one out. I have a HTML page with a form, and once the user clicks submit an external python script is called using celery. I have a view that can check if the celery job is done, but how do I continually poll the database to check if my job is done? Is there a way to "refresh" the view so that it continually polls the job status? I know you can do this in javascript, but I'm not sure how to integrate this with Django (is there some sort of module...)? Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: You should take a look to signals: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/

Comment: @DavidW. how do Signals help?

Comment: "how do I continually poll the database to check if my job is done?" -> usually you don't, you send an event/signal/whatever when the job is done. However, if the whole purpose is to change display of a page without realoding it, Ajax is what you're looking for (cf. Matt answer)

Comment: What I'm going for is to have a simple view that displays with "Process is running..." and when the process is done, display a new HTML page. I wanted the view to continually check the job status, but maybe Ajax/Javascript is the way to go?

Answer (score 3):

You can redirect yourself to your own html (https://realpython.com/django-redirects/)
On your view.py, after the 'POST' case:

```
return redirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. What you're looking for is Javascript and Ajax. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306981) is a good answer.

Comment: Thanks, the post you gave is pretty detailed. Where would I place the Ajax call exactly? Within my Django view?

Comment: The Ajax call would be in your Javascript. The Django view is what will be responding to the Ajax call.