# Best approach to create rich dynamic single page Django web application as it relates to CSS/HTML

Tags: jquery, css, django, html, responsive-design

I am a new web developer and will be developing a simple "single-page" web application using Django.  I'm not a graphic artist at all.  I've been able to setup a simple form which looks pretty ugly but pretty much has the functionality.  I'm basically generating raw html from Django views and just putting them on a white page.

Is it possible to purchase a theme such as below 
http://themeforest.net/item/quick-admin-template/4940725

and integrate into Django?   Is there a certain style/type I should purchase that works well with Django. (like HTML5,  Bootstrap, CSS, Angular JS, etc..)   I'm just learning this so not that familiar with the design component.  I know I'll have to edit the html a little bit to work with Django and I think I'm okay with that.

Basically my application will have a few features such as a base form to enter data, A monitor page, and a few admin pages.  I'd like to use Ajax/Jquery to make it a "single page" application.

I like the look of the tabs/accordian on the side and top.

All of these admin templates have a ton of pages/features/etc...    My guess is that I just use what I need and I can take the rest out?   Is this correct?

Thanks for your help. Just looking for some simple guidance regarding best approach to create a rich looking single-page application in Django.  Any help would be appreciated to get me on the right page!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get any template and adapt it to your needs. You will need to set up views to handle your ajax calls.

[Read the documentation on templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/) to get a solid base of how to fill your page initially...then keep it updated with ajax as you would in any other system.
For basic usage of ajax and django you can see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306981/how-do-i-integrate-ajax-with-django-applications). In general terms you set a view to serve your requests and return your data serialized as json.

The forms can be made from [django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) and loaded directly from there (and validated).

Make sure you finish the [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) as it is important to grasp the basics of the framework.

Answer (score 1):

Django doesn't sound the ideal choice for what you want to do. Better choose a lighter framework. But should you stick with Django, after completing [its tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/), have a closer look at how its [ORM](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/#the-model-layer) works, as well as the [authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/), since you will be using these two components the most in the application you described.

Now for single page apps, it is worth using the [Django REST framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/), which would make your life a lot easier.

For the front-end, you already mentioned Bootstrap and AngularJS, both are good choices to keep the CSS and Javascript organized and maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to purchase a theme such as below http://themeforest.net/item/quick-admin-template/4940725 and integrate into Django?

Yes

> Is there a certain style/type I should purchase that works well with Django?

No. Django works well with html/css/jquery/etc.

> All of these admin templates have a ton of pages/features/etc... My guess is that I just use what I need and I can take the rest out? Is this correct?

Basically yes.

> Any help would be appreciated to get me on the right page!

I recommend you follow this tutorial to learn the basics on how to use Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/