# Get complete parameter in URL including special characters

Tags: python-3.x, django, get, python-requests

```
http://localhost:8000/pary/?url=https://jobs.chegg.com/#categoryName#-jobs&uid=OIKAHY&env_id=4
```

In my Django views for **pary** function, for the above url, when I am doing `data = request.GET.get('url')` I am getting data as `https://jobs.chegg.com/` instead of `https://jobs.chegg.com/#categoryName#-jobs`

Its ignoring all the content after **# keyword**. Please suggest how to get the complete url parameter value in python.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_full_path) will help? Yes, it might only include the relative URL, but you can simply append the domain before it.

Comment: I dont need the domain, in the example you shared I want the parameter value for **print** which is **true** but it doesnt get that

Comment: The parameter `?print=true` is only a demo from the Django documentation and I can't see it anywhere in your code. All I meant is that this function in my answer returns the full url.

Comment: yes, I mean when I tried with code, I got `http://localhost:8000/url/`
What I mean in my previous comment is that I wanted the `true` as output from that example so that I will use the same in my code to get `https://jobs.chegg.com/#categoryName#-jobs`

Comment: From all I know, the `#` is a feature only limited in browsers. It's called an anchor and it only directs to a certain section on the web page, which won't be recognized by the browser. You might have to get the full URL in javascript [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp) and pass it back to the Django server as a string [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27100825/how-pass-javascript-function-s-value-to-django-view).

Comment: Got it, but unfortunately, I cannot pass it from JavaScript because its an `href` click in html page