# Django custom template tags in javascript

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I have a custom template tag that returns suppose name of a student and roll number if passed as an argument id of the student.

```
@register.inclusion_tag('snippet/student_name.html')
def st_name_tag(profile, disp_roll=True, disp_name=True):
    #some calculations
    return {'full_name':student.name,
            'roll':student.roll_number,
           }
```

The template(included) consists of some Html file which is written in a single line(to avoid `unterminated string literal` error from js).

I simply want to call the `st_name_tag` from inside the JS function.

My JS looks like:

```
{% load profile_tag %}
<script type = "text/javascript">   
eventclick : function(st){
     var div = ('<div></div>');
     var st_id = st.id;
     if (st.status == 'pass'){
          div.append('<p>Student Name:{% st_name_tag '+st_id+' %}</p>');
     }
}
```

So far I tried the above method along with removing the `+` and `''` signs from `st_id` varaible. That hasnt helped me at all. Help Please!

Comment: You cannot do that. You cannot mix client-side logic with server-side logic because the template is already rendered on server before anything happens with javascript. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I am trying to load a template on a javascript click event.

Comment: You would have to use ajax for that matter. http://stackoverflow.com/a/28341345/940098

Comment: Hey, thanks for all the informations about the server-side and client-side logics. I knew about that but just never thought that far :). I have another question for you since Im still stuck in this one. The tag includes a template and the template is of certain format(layout) and is uniformly used everywhere throughout the project and need to use it in this context too. I used ajax like you suggested  and did this `form.append('<p>Added By:{% profile_name_tag user_id %}</p>');` inside the success function. But doesnot works.

Comment: I posted an answer based on our comments. I would advise you to open a new question and I would be eager to help you, this is vague right now.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to render a template based on the interaction by user. The first happens on the server (server-side as it is often referred to), and the latter happens on the user's browser.

The order that these happen is first to render the template on server, send and present in browser, then user interacts with js. Because of this fact, as I mentioned in the comment, it is not possible to affect the template rendered within javascript.

I would recommend you to use [ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28341345/940098) in order to accomplish this. Whenever an iteraction occurs, you asynchronously make a request to the server to present you with new data.