# Javascript in custom Django template tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, templatetags

I know it is possible to use a Django variable in Javascript, but is it possible to use a Javascript string as an argument in a custom template tag?

e.g.

```
 var source = {{ censuses|to_JSON:$('#id_census-0-survey').val()|safe }}
```

where `to_JSON` is a registered template tag

Django 1.10 / Jquery 2.1.3

Comment: This question might shed some light - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30909752/django-custom-template-tags-in-javascript

Comment: @BorkoKovacev This is an assumption, but I am not positive it needs `ajax`. It work as perfectly when I pass it the written out string, but raises an error when pass the variable (which is defined at this point).

Comment: Where do you think django's template is rendered and where do you think javascript is executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to use JavaScript as an argument in a custom template tag or a template filter.  Templates are rendered on the server side, and JavaScript runs in the browser.