# How to apply ajax call to all model objects in DJANGO

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, django-views

I need to implement AJAX and its working fine. However, I am having problem in applying ajax to each instance of a model. It's just being applied on the top Object and applying ajax call on the same page. For remaining objects, when I click on  the link its directing me to new page and showing me JSON objects which I dont want.

Views.py

```
def upvote(request, post_id):

if request.method == "POST":
    p = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)
    p.upvote += 1
    p.save()
    return JsonResponse({'count':p.upvote })

if request.method == "GET":
    p = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)
    p.upvote += 1
    p.save()
    data = {
        'count' : p.upvote,
    }
    return JsonResponse({'count': p.upvote})
```

Urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)/upvote/$', views.upvote, name='upvote-detail'),
```

Views.html

```
<script>
    $(function(){
       $('#up_vote').click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          window.alert("hello");
          console.log("hello");


          $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('href'),
            type :'get' ,
            success : function (data){
              // alert('success');
              $('#upvote_count').html(data.count);
            },
            failure : function (data){
              alert('failure') ; 
            }
          }) ;  // ajax call 

       }); // upvote link call
</script>

<div id="columns">
    {% for post in object_list %}

        <div class="pin">
            <a href="/posts/{{ post.id }}/">

            <img src= "/static/media/{{post.image}}" />
            </a>
            <p>
                {{post.description}}
                (<a href="{% url "post-edit" pk=post.id %}">edit</a>)
            </p>


            <div style="float:left">
              <a href='{% url 'upvote-detail' post.id %}' id='up_vote'>Up vote  </a>
              <span id='upvote_count'> {{ post.upvote }} </span> 
            </div>


            <div style="float:right">
              <a href='{% url 'downvote-detail' post.id %}' id='down_vote'> Down vote </a>
              <span id='downvote_count'>{{post.downvote}}</span>
            </div>


        </div>
    {% endfor %}

    </div>
```

Here is my all the files. Currently AJAX call is working absolutely fine. Its just applying on the top (first) of object in for LOOP. For Remaining objects, when I click on link, it render me to new page. Could someone identify the problem? 
Thanks,

Comment: basically return a `JsonResponse`, a complete answer on how to implement ajax would be too broad for stack overflow, it is already shown in the documentation too

Comment: @Sayse Can you tell me where I can find documentation? or any helpful link

Comment: It took me about 15 seconds to find [the answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20307569/5098707). Please, do some research before asking.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#ajax-example

Answer (score 1):

in views.py

```
def detail(request):
    return render(request, 'detail.html', {'posts': Post.objects.all()})

def upvote(request, post_id):
   if request.method == "POST":
       p = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)
       p.upvote += 1
       p.save()
       return JsonResponse({'count':p.upvote })
   return JsonResponse({})
```

in detail.html:

```
{% for post in posts %}
     <a href='{% url 'upvote-detail' post.id %}' id='up_voite'>Up voite <span id='voite_count'> {{ post.upvote }} </span> </a>
 {% endfor %}

<script>
    $(function(){
       $('#up_voite').click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $.post($(this).attr('href'), function(data) {
              $(this).find('span').html(data.upvote);
          });
       });
    });
</script>
```

code is not checked

Comment: This is good, except that you really shouldn't do db-modifying actions on a GET. Might as well make the JS do a POST and check that in the upvote function.

Comment: @comalex3 Thanks. For some reason its not updating the upvote data. Instead {{ post.upvote }} remains same. <a> tag does show the link but its not updating the upvote and not displaying on span tag.

Comment: @user3487775 debug your code, that debug javascript use console.log(), alert() or yours browser debug toolbar that debug python code use print() or pdb (ipdb), see that returns a post request ... you will understand why the code does not work

Comment: @comalex3  Thanks for help. Its showing json response, but instead of updating on the same page, its redirecting me to the new page and showing me json response on new page.

Comment: @user3487775 You probably have an error in the javascript or or forgot e.preventDefault();

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def upvote(request, post_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)
    errors = []
    data = {}
    try:
        p.upvote += 1
        p.save()
        data = {
            'success': 1,
        }
    except:
        errors.append(['There was an error'])
        data = {
            'success': 0,
            'errors':errors,
        }
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data))
```