# Django template not refreshing for loop after pickerselect selection

Tags: javascript, django, twitter-bootstrap

I need to update an html table cell, which is created using a Django template for loop, once the selection of the pickerselect has changed.  My HTML for the table:

```
        <tbody>
            {% for task in tasks %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ task.taskNumber }}</td>
                <td>{{ task.taskDescription }}</td>
                <td><div name="dataOutput">{{task.thisPeriod}}</div></td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
```

My HTML for the pickerselect:

```
    <select name="selValue" class="selectpicker">
        <option value="1">Current Period ({{currentPeriod}})</option>
        <option value="2">Previous Period ({{previousPeriod}})</option>
    </select>
```

My javascript:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  $(function() {
      $('.selectpicker').on('change', function(){
        var selected = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
        var updateArray = document.getElementsByName("dataOutput");
        for (var i = 0; 1 < updateArray.length; i++) {
            if (selected == 1) {
                updateArray[i].innerHTML = "{{task.thisPeriod}}";
            } else if (selected == 2) {
                updateArray[i].innerHTML = "temp";
            } 
         }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

At this point, the table row values update with the placeholder "temp" when selection 2 is made but when I change back to selection 1, no values appear in the table.  I assume that this is because the Django template for loop is not being refreshed so it doesn't know how to render for the specific task in the loop {{task.thisPeriod}}.  I have looked through a number of questions about refreshing div's using javascript but nothing has been effective... I always get the same result of blank values in the table.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of obvious, but you can't do it just like that, because javascript doesn't record the `tasks` django context that you passed to the template. You should use ajax to pass the selected value to a separate method in `views.py`, in there you find out the data and return it to the javascript, then render the `div` with the new data.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it was something along those lines.  I am new to ajax/javascript so would you mind providing an example?

Comment: There are tons of examples online. I randomly googled and found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306981/how-do-i-integrate-ajax-with-django-applications. Apparently you have to read jquery ajax doc as well: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/