# Where and how to calculate total price depending on date range user selected?

Tags: python, ajax, django

i'm working on site for renting rooms. User picks 2 dates(UserStartDate & UserEndDate).

with this python code i gonna get number of days in his date range:

```
user_date_range = [endUser - timedelta(i) for i in range((endUser - startUser).days+1)] 
user_range_num_days = len(user_date_range)
```

and i have a day price for room: 20$

but due to lack of proficiency in Django,I can't figure out how to calculate user price according to his date range. And where it should be done.

hope for your help.

Comment: I think you are confused about Django-- thats a web framework. Your problem is python.. research using timedelta. And subtracting two dates.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have anything to do with django but rather python. I assume `user_start_date` and `user_end_date` are both python `datetime.date` or `datetime.datetime` objects, then you could do:

```
num_days = (user_end_date - user_start_date).days
total_price = num_days * 20
```

Comment: thank you man i'll use it. But I want to know where this logic should be implemented.

Comment: Wherever you want to calculate the price apparently. Where does that happen?

Comment: So far,  I meet user_end_date & user_start_date (sent by GET request ) via **def get()** in my View. In the future want to dynamically reload price text via AJAX, so the user can see his calculated price instantly.

Comment: Then do it in the ajax call, right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306981/how-do-i-integrate-ajax-with-django-applications

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html

A calendar is necessary as you should be aware that not all months have the same amount of days in them. itermonthdates(year, month) returns an iterator for all days in the month. Run through that iterator and increment a count for every date match within the range. Of course if the end date extends into the next month keep the same counter.