# How to get an element from list based on clicked link in Django Template?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-bootstrap3

I'm creating private messages application, and I render my messages this way:

```
return render(request,'mssg/mssg_page.html', {'inbox':inbox, 'current_mssg':current_mssg,})
```

Inbox contain all messages. Current message is a one that should be fully displayed. I made a list of messages that look like this in my template:

```
{% for mssg in inbox %}
    <a href="#"><!-- here -->
       <div class="right">
          <h3>{{ mssg.mssg_from.username }} <small>{{ mssg.delivery_date }}</small></h3>
          <h2>{{ mssg.title|safe }}</h2>
          <p>{{ mssg.text|safe|truncatewords:15  }}</p>
       </div>
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

I display full current message in same template too.
I wants to change current message after clicking on link with `<!-- here -->` commment
I know that I can send message id to view, validate it and send it back to template. But it needs page to be refreshed. However all messages are already in template listed in `inbox` so there should be no need to refresh page. I also know that it's possible to pick an message from inbox like this `{{inbox.0}}` 
But I have no idea how to make it depended on clicked link. I guess that javascript is needed for it. But I even if I know that I can do something like `inbox[0]` by placing `inbox.0` in template I still don't know how to do something like `inbox[varriable]`.
Is there a way to do it?
I don't want my page to refresh if it don't have to do it.
PS I'm using bootsrap

Comment: I think you should use an Ajax call to request your view with message so that you can validate that this is requesting  for <!--here--> . Ajax call will get you data without refreshing page and you can show the result on the same page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I integrate Ajax with Django applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306981/how-do-i-integrate-ajax-with-django-applications)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using AJAX will solve your problem. See [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20307569/2532070) which explains how to do that:

```
$('a').click(function() { // This is a listener to the link you mentioned.
    $.ajax({
        url: '127.0.0.1:8000/your_ajax_url', // You will need to create a URL for your AJAX call.
        type: 'get', // This is the default though, you don't actually need to always mention it
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        failure: function(data) { 
            alert('Got an error dude');
        }
    }); 
}
```