# How to trigger a function with checkbox django

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap, python-2.7, templates

I wanna know how I run certain functions depending on the selected checkboxes. This is my visual template:[image: Template]

and this is the code I have for my template is called admin.html:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <p><button type="button" class="btn btn-black"><i class="fa fa-upload"  </i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="bold">IMPORT ALL</span></button>  </p>
    <p>  Import selected reports:</p>
    <p>  <label><input type="checkbox" value=""> Cisco Backlog Report</label></p>
    <p>  <label><input type="checkbox" value=""> Planning & Standard</label></p>
    <p>  <label><input type="checkbox" value=""> Emo Trans Report</label></p>
    <p>  <label><input type="checkbox" value=""> Phyllis Report</label></p>
    <p>  <label><input type="checkbox" value=""> Purchase Order View</label></p>
    <p>  <label><input type="checkbox" value=""> On Hand Inventory</label></p>
    <p>  <label><input type="checkbox" value=""> Bill of Material</label></p>
    <p>  <label><input type="checkbox" value=""> Aged</label></p>
    <p>  <label><input type="checkbox" value=""> Shipment with Times</label></p>
    <p><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Import</button>  </p>
```

As I mentioned before, I got 10 functions that read several .csv reports and upload the data into models and I trigger them with the URL section. In my views.py I will show two examples:

```
def importpurchase(request)
    Log logic here
def importcisco(request) 
    Log logic here
def importall(request) # this function is to import all
    importpurchase(None)
    importcisco(None)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can receive list of selected checkboxes using `request.POST.getlist('mycheckboxname')`, you should give your checkboxes `name` and `value` accordingly to selected field ('Aged' for example):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckboxname" value="Aged">
```

Then you can call any function depending on what selected in list:

```
def func1(l,vals):
  process_values_in_different_way(l, vals)...
def func2(l,vals):
 process_values(l, vals)...

def MyView(request):
 values=get_values_from_somewhere()
 mylist=request.POST.getlist('mycheckboxname')
 if 'Aged' in mylist:
    func2(mylist, values)
 elif anotherValue in mylist:
    func2(mylist, values)
 elif...
    etc
```

**EDIT(on your comments):**

This is how django works: your client send request and you return response. This is called HTTP protocol. When IMPORT button is clicked your client send a form which contains all data entered by the user to the server. This data appears as a part of `request object` in your view. You can retrieve this data and you can do everything you want with this data. In my example process_values can, for example, select all 'Phyllis Report' objects and return them to response, as part of rendered template. There is no other way how you can do it. You cant just call on click function from server without request. To accomplish what you want you can try to split your logic and put part of it to javascript. You will be able to bound onclick listener to your button and then send requests through `ajax` to server. But this is a whole new story.
This might be useful: [ajax and django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306981/how-do-i-integrate-ajax-with-django-applications)

Comment: I think I getting it, but what about this: def func1(l,vals):
  process_values_in_different_way(l, vals)...
def func2(l,vals):
 process_values(l, vals)... Can you be more detailed?

Comment: yeah, i will modify answer in a second

Comment: and another thing, what about the IMPORT button, once is clicked it should trigger the functions selected on the checkboxes

Comment: alright so in "values" I should list all the names of the checklist right or my functions?

Comment: you should list all the names of the checklist in values, as on your picture, and in view you call your functions accordingly to values which have been selected. If bill of materials and aged in values you call function related to them, i don't know how to explain it better

Comment: got it, THANKS ! :)