# How to avoid additional random number in DataTables ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, datatables

Hi my datatables ajax call is as below,

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#example').DataTable({
            "ajax": '/api/get_requests'
        });
```

So I am expecting the call my backend django server as below,

```
http://localhost:8080/api/get_requests/
```

But instead it generates an additional random numbers in the end and call is sent as below and my django server says wrong url and gives 404 error

```
http://localhost:8080/api/get_requests/?_=1511021359038
```

How can I force the datatables ajax call to not send the additional random numbers

Comment: are you sure that the ajax is right, by the way why you are hardcoding the URL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I integrate Ajax with Django applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306981/how-do-i-integrate-ajax-with-django-applications)

Comment: I am not hard coding the IP address (localhost) , URL is the request url which will be handled by django (/api/get_requests/). Now the issue is not with integration. It is sending an extra random number at the end during any request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not random numbers but a timestamp, the above translates into `Sat Nov 18 2017 17:09:19 GMT+0100 (CET)`.

It is simply how jQuery AJAX cache works, it adds a timestamp to the request to fool the browsers attempt to cache everything. I believe

```
$('#example').DataTable({
  ajax: {
    cache: false,
    url: '/api/get_requests'
  }
});
```

will fix the issue.