# How do I pass Javascript variables from my html template page to a Django views function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I am working on a Django environment. 
I have created a form in my html page which contains a textbox for input for a label like "Enter your name" . 
I have a submit button below the textbox. 
I need to pass the inputted name to the button as a value and then this button value is to be passed to a python function in views.py.

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: To reach to django, you must reach to the server. You reach to the server by performing a request. Read about ajax with django.

Comment: i think you mean you don't want to refresh the page. just execute a function on click? if so you need to use `XMLhttprequest` or `Ajax`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I integrate Ajax with Django applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306981/how-do-i-integrate-ajax-with-django-applications)

Comment: @mohammed qudah Yes exactly. I don't want to refresh the page. I want to execute a function on click with the button value being passed to the function in the backend

Comment: i will answer the question, the solution will be using jQuery

Comment: @mohammed qudah Thank you man

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to use Ajax, its like calling a url in the background without affecting the user. but first to call a a url(view) we need a url and a view. so i will think you have something like this

```
url('^click/btn/(?P<data>[0-9]+)', views.click_btn, name="btn_click");
```

and the view

```
def click_btn(request, data):
    # do whatever you want with the data....
    return HttpResponse('Done')
```

now to call this from the fron-end we will use `jQuery.ajax`

first you have the button

```
<button id="btn_click">Click me!</button>
```

now create a script tag and type the following

> the script tag must be after the button so he can see it

```
<!-- if you haven't included jQuery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
// get your input value...
var data = $('#my_input').val();
$.ajax({
    url: `/click/btn/${data}`,
    success: function (res) {
    // every code in this function will execute when Ajax call the url
    alert(`Nice! you called the url and get this data: ${res}`)
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Bro.. I tried your exact code.. I am able to get the alert.. But the data variable is still not getting passed to the views.py function or so it seems.

Comment: if the alert is showing that means it is working? your data should be after `get this data: here***` in the alert text

Comment: what is your alert text?

Comment: No issues bro.. It's working. There was a small error from my side. Thanks for the answer