# How can I render a plot in Django made on the server via matplotlib?

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

I'm developing a Django application where I'd like to be able to render a graph that updates when a user checks/unchecks checkbox inputs. I'm having trouble getting the data from the form to my server-side logic, and then rendering the plot (a histogram created via matplotlib) in the view.

The data comes from a SQL query in the sqlite database that comes prepackaged in Django. I have verified that the SQL query returns the correct data, and have a script that will create the correct histogram. However, since there are many different options for the user to click to generate the histogram, I'd like to not save each potential histogram as a static file to be served. Ideally, the histogram would update when the user toggles a checkbox.

I'm not opposed to using JavaScript/another plotting framework to render the histogram, however I'm not sure how I'd connect that to the database or to the view.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE WITH EXAMPLE**

The checkboxes are options for the user to include/exclude in the histogram. Toggling them on and off will create a subset of the full dataset returned by the SQL query. Here's an example:

If there was a survey of preferred ice cream flavor and topping, the query return a dataframe like this (except with more flavors and toppings provided):

```
import pandas as pd
# Query from DB creates this via pd.read_sql_query(), but I'll just create by hand
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'flavor': ['chocolate', 'strawberry', 'vanilla', 'pineapple', 'chocolate'],
    'topping': ['fudge', 'sprinkles', 'fruit', 'cookies', 'sprinkles']
})
```

The checkboxes create a subset of the checked ice cream flavors, and the histogram shows the distribution of preferred toppings. So if chocolate and strawberry are checked, we get:

```
sub = df[df['flavor'].isin(['chocolate', 'strawberry'])]
```

From `sub`, I can calculate the percentage of responses for each topping. I have logic to handle this, so I'll just shortcut to the `final` dataframe that will be used to make the histogram:

```
final = pd.DataFrame({
    'topping': ['fudge', 'sprinkles'],
    'pct_liked': [.333, .666]
})
```

Lastly, I plot the histogram:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = final['pct_liked'].plot(
    kind = 'bar',
    title = f'Ice Cream Toppings by Chocolate and Strawberry Lovers',
    width = 1.0
)

ax.figure
```

And *this* is the histogram that I want to display in my Django view. I've verified that this workflow in the script works properly.

The database where the responses would be stored is the sqlite database that comes with Django, but I'm unsure how to take the checkboxes for the flavors that the user clicks and pass them through this process, then how to take `ax` and render it in the Django view.

Comment: This doesn't completely address all the specifics of what you're asking to do, but addresses the general idea. You need to make AJAX requests when the user toggles the checkbox, or interacts with some other element of the page. That request would return the updated image of the histogram. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306981/how-do-i-integrate-ajax-with-django-applications

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm still a bit confused; if the AJAX request requires a url, I would just be passing the same one to it. And the function to handle the data (and subsequently render the histogram) is written in Python. Would I have to rewrite all of this code in JS? I can provide more specifics as well if it would help.

Comment: Yes, more specifics would be helpful - this is all straightforward and do-able, just a little complicated the first time you do it.

Comment: Updated with an example.

Comment: Do you have the initial view with the checkboxes set up already?

Comment: Yes. Created the checkboxes in the template, and have verified that they are working correctly.