# Passing variable from javascript to django views

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I am creating simple "rock paper scissors" game with some css animations and so on, where most of the stuff happens in javascript, as learning JS is what I am focusing on mostly at the moment.

User vs computer match also happens in javascript. When match is finished I am assigning users earned exp(points) to new variable.

What I am trying to do now is sending that data (earned exp) to the views, so I can save it back in a database (users.exp).

I think jQuery ajax or fetch api should do that if I am right but after hours of trying I probably just don't get it.

Any1 can give me some tips, explanation? Not just solution please.

Views:

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user = request.user  
        userObj = Profile.objects.filter(user=user)

        usersLevel = userObj[0].level
        usersPoints = userObj[0].points
        context = { 
            'usersLevel': usersLevel,
            'usersPoints': usersPoints,
        }   
        return render(request, 'rps_app/game.html', context)

    else:
        print('No user logged in!')
        return render(request, 'rps_app/game.html')
```

This is my template where Iam loading users data:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        var usersLevel = '{{usersLevel|safe}}';
        var usersPoints = '{{usersPoints|safe}}';
</script>
```

js:

```
let users_level = Number(usersLevel);
let users_points = Number(usersPoints);
progressbar.style.width = `${users_points}%`;
...
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn-ajax').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/game',
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",
            type: 'get', 

            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                alert(data);
            },
            failure: function(data) { 
                alert('Your code is crap mate');
            }
        }); 
    });
})
```

************ .    E D I T E D    . ***********

Thats what I got now:

```
js:

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn-ajax').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/earned_exp=100/',
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",
            success: function(data) {
                alert('succes');
            },
            failure: function(data) { 
                alert('Your code is crap mate');
}}); });})

views:

def pass_variable(request, earned_exp=None):

    some_variable = request.GET.get('earned_exp')
    console.log(some_variable)

    return HttpResponse('<h1>ok.{}</h1>'.format(earned_exp))

url:

path('test/<earned_exp>/', user_views.pass_variable, name='pass_variable'),
```

Comment: Where's the AJAX code you tried? Did you check the xhr in the browser's console?

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306981/how-do-i-integrate-ajax-with-django-applications

Comment: I have edited my post

Comment: try to use cookie

Comment: It may work but its not a sollution I need to know how to do that with ajax... Thanks @Chris G will check that

Comment: I edited my post @Chris G. Its working Iam getting the alert and the console is printing the data. The problem is I still dont get the concept I mean should I pass that data in the succes: as json, back to templates and then to the views or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass variables as URL parameters and get them through the request object.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'mycoolwebsite.com/path/?earned_xp=100'
    success: function(e){
       alert("success");          
    },  
    error: function(e){
       alert("error")
    }   
});


class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request):
       xp = request.GET.get("earned_xp")
       # do whatever you want with the XP now.
```

In case you want to send multiple URL parameters, you can seperate them by `&` here's an example url

https://example.com/`?hello=world&goodbye=coding`

Comment: which link are you talking about?

Comment: see my edited post... Why when trying console.log() or alert() I am getting "name 'console' is not defined" error? Still doing something wrong

Comment: `console.log()` is javascript syntax, which you're trying to use on python. Use print(some_variable)