# How to show data in popup with server side processing in Django templates (popup)

Tags: jquery, django, database, django-templates

Here, I have a Django form and view.

I am displaying the data from db using datatables in Django template.

Now I want the view functionality when, I click on view button it should render corresponding row data in popup boxlike "https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-types/bootstrap4-modal.html"

How can we achieve this with Django templates?

service.html

```
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="id_veh" class="control-label">
                                            Car
                                        </label>
                                        <div class="controls ">
                                                {{ervice.veh_id}}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="id_service_date" class="control-label">
                                            Service Dtae
                                        </label>
                                        <div class="controls ">
                                                {{service.service_date}}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="id_kms" class="control-label">
                                            Kms
                                        </label>
                                        <div class="controls ">
                                                {{service.kms}}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

views.py

```
    def add_edit_servicing(request, id=None, service=None):
        #
        if id:
            service = Service.objects.get(pk=id)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ServiceForm(request.POST, request=request)
            if form.is_valid():
                ......
                .....
                service.save()


        context = {
            'menu': 'active',
            'submenu':'active',
            'form': form,
            'id':id,
            'service':service,
        }

        return render(request, 'service.html', context=context)
```

list.html

```
      <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="box-body">
                            <table id="service" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Veh</th>
                                        <th>Service Date</th>
                                        <th>KMS</th>
                                        <th>View</th>

                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    {% endblock %}

    {% block scripts %}
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.0/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/plugins/datatables/dataTables.editor.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/plugins/datatables/editor.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.extend(true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
                    columnDefs: [
                        {
                            targets: '_all',
                            defaultContent: ''
                        }
                    ]
                });
                var table = $('#service').DataTable({
                    "pageLength": 100,
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "bSearchable":true,
                    "dom": 'blfrtip',
                    "ajax": "/maint/dt/car_service/?format=datatables",
                    "columns": [
                        {
                            "data": "c.number"
                        },
                        {
                            "data": "service_date"
                        },
                        {
                            "data": "kms"
                        },

                        {
                        "data": "id",
                        "bSortable": false,
                        "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                            return '<a class="btn btn-sm  btn-primary" href="srv/service' + full.id + '/view">' + 'View' + '</a>';
                        }
                    }]
                });

            });
            function getCookie(name) {
                var cookieValue = null;
                if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
                    var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                        var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                        // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                        if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                            cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return cookieValue;
            }
            var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

            function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
                // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
                return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
            }
            $.ajaxSetup({
                beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
                    if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                    }
                }
            });
        </script>
        {% endblock %}
```

Mentioned datatable ("https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-types/bootstrap4-modal.html") functionality is not working for me to populate the data.

Thankyou

Comment: use ajax call follow this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306981/how-do-i-integrate-ajax-with-django-applications

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I know that I will have to use AJAX call but I don't know ajax n all.