# How do you pre-populate a Django form from a model

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a Django form that is is generated from a model

**model.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    email_address = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

[image]

The user Dropbox is populated (automatically) from the users

How can I pre-populate the form from the *Profile* model when I select user?

Comment: Can you give more details about what you're trying to do? You could mean selecting a user and the other fields populating based on some user or other model, the other case I can think of is that you're trying to update a profile and the fields aren't populating.

Comment: @schillingt Question updated. Is that clearer?

Comment: So you're updating existing profiles? The only way is to make an ajax request each time the user changes the value of the dropdown to fetch the profile of the corresponding user and if it exists, update the fields in javascript. Look up ajax + django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this either by submitting the form whenever the user field is changed or you can use Ajax to do this asynchronously. Both require a bit of JavaScript code.  The first option requires that you use a modelform. The steps are pretty standard.

1. Submit the user data
2. Find the user in your database
3. Load the user instance into your modelform
4. Pass your form to the context variable

For Ajax, search for tutorials on Ajax and see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20307569/3549766) on SO.

In your HTML:

```
<select name="user_selector" id="userDropDown" class=" whatever-custom-css-class" autofocus onChange="this.form.submit();">
```

Then, inside your get requet, you can

```
user_name = self.request.GET.get('user_selector', None)
if user_name:
    try:
        selected_user = User.objects.get(username = user_name)

    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        # No such user. 
        selected_user = None

if selected_user:
    contact_form = ContactForm(instance = selected_user)
    ...
    context.update({'form': contact_form})
    return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```