# Wrong redirection of url in django

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax, django-views

**Updated Question:**

Wrong redirection of URL in Django. I have this:

`views.py`.

```
def graph(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'text' in request.POST:
        print("testing....")
        print(request.POST.get('text'))
        name = request.POST.get('text')
        context = {
            'name': name,
        }
        print(context)
        return render(request, 'StockPrediction/chart.html', context)
    else:
        return render(request, 'StockPrediction/greet.html')
```

`urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.greet, name='greet'),
    path("index/", views.index, name='Stock Prediction'),
    path("prediction/", views.prediction, name='Prediction'),
    path("view/", views.graph, name='Graph'),
]
```

for testing purposes, I m using a print statement. So there is no problem until printing `print(context)` but the problem is it goes to `'StockPrediction/greet.html'` not `'StockPrediction/chart.html'`. which I need.

Comment: remove `'s` in `company's symbol` to improve formatting.

Comment: why `request.POST` should have `_graph` in its keys?

Comment: Then what it should be??

Comment: nothing. `if request.method == 'POST'` is enough. or with `and request.is_ajax()`

Comment: `'_graph' in request.POST:` to because I have two submit button.

Comment: Hey, I m able to solve the problem but there is the wrong redirection of URL. I have updated the question, please help.

Comment: better to post `new question` not to update your question over and over to new one.

Comment: I m not able to post a new question that's why I have to edit this.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306981/how-do-i-integrate-ajax-with-django-applications, an answer to your last question, it's so rare not to find out question's answer in stackoverflow and, try to give feedback to the community spend time to answer your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'YOUR VIEW URL',
    data: {'row': row, 'text': text},
    success: function (data){
        DO SOMETHING HERE if VIEW has no errors
    })
```

in your view:

```
row = request.POST.get('row')    
text = request.POST.get('text')
```

also you should care about crsf-token. [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request)

Comment: Hey, I have updated the question. can look into it.

Comment: replace  if request.method == 'POST' to if request.is_ajax(). Do you have any errors in browser console or django errors?

Comment: No, but it goes into `else` condition

Comment: Please help me.

Comment: Hey, I m able to solve the problem but there is the wrong redirection of URL. I have updated the question, please help.

Comment: do you have the results of print("testing....") and print(request.POST.get('text')) in your console?

Comment: Yes. actually this account does not allow me to post more question so here updated question from different account. it so urgent I have to submit this project. here the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62457035/ajax-sending-data-twice-in-views-py-django

Answer (score 0):

your can `POST` it `GET` it or put it as a variable in your `url`. here is a post approach:

using `jquery` :

```
$.ajax({
    url : "/URL/to/view", 
    type : "POST", // or GET depends on you
    data : { text: $text },
    async: false,
    // handle a successful response
    success : function(json) {
         // some code to do with response
         }
    },

    // handle a non-successful response
    error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
        $('#results').html("<div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert>Oops! We have encountered an error: "+errmsg+
            " <a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>"); // add the error to the dom
        console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
    }
});
```

In your view you can get the data as json and return josn as response

```
import json
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
         response_data = {}   // to return something as json response
         text = request.POST['text']
         ...
         return HttpResponse(
         json.dumps(response_data),
         content_type="application/json"
    else:
        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps({"nothing to see": "this isn't happening"}),
            content_type="application/json"
        )
```

Comment: Hey, I have updated the question. can look into it.