# Ajax sending data twice in views.py django

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax, django-views

I have this `form` in `index.html` and two submit button on clicking on one button named `.graph-btn`
I m using jquery and ajax to send data from `form` to Django.

**Code:**
`index.html`

```
 <form action="{% url 'Graph' %}" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                <table class="table table-striped table-dark" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead class="bg-info">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Company's Symbol</th>
                        <th>Current Price</th>
                        <th>View Current chart</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {% for a,b in stocks %}
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row" class="comp_name">{{ a }}</th>
                        <td>{{ b }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn graph-btn" name="_graph" value="View Graph">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn predict-btn" formaction="{% url 'Graph' %}" name="_predict" value="Predict Closing Price">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                </form>
```

```
<script>
    $(".graph-btn").click(function(e) {
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var $text = $row.find(".comp_name").text();
    var name = $text;
    console.log(name);
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        url:'{% url 'Graph' %}',
        data:{
            'text': name,
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken':$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
        },
        success:function(json){
        },
        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

here I want to take data from `th` row named `.comp_name` and pass the data to views.py in Django.
There is problem is Ajax.

`views.py`

```
def graph(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("testing....")
        print(request.body)
        print(request.POST.get('text'))
        name = request.POST.get('text')
        context = {
            'name': name,
        }
        print(context)
        return render(request, 'StockPrediction/chart.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'StockPrediction/greet.html')
```

I m using Print statement to check if everything is fine. the **problem** is that when I click on `.graph-btn` it throws me two iterative values. First one is the right but the second one is `None`.
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lPTd.png)

Help me, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shoudn't use jquery class selector. use id selector(“#id”). Now it happens because you have more then one button with 'graph-btn' class. Just assign IDs to your buttons in for loop ( {% for a,b in stocks %})

Comment: Can you explain with code? and also where is more than one button with that class.

Comment: how many buttons with 'View Graph' value do you see on your page?

Comment: Much appreciate your effort but it's still the same.

Comment: there is 50 buttons with different {{ a }}

Comment: so you have 50 ajax calls in your javascript

Comment: no. I have only one ajax call with `.graph-btn` click functionality.

Comment: Here is the video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_17E-B7tvNc

Comment: give me your skype)

Comment: do use anydesk? for screensharing?

Answer (score 0):

if clause must be below
`if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():`