# How to correctly post with jQuery / Ajax in Django model

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-models

I am trying to `POST` data using jQuery/Ajax to my Django related models. Despite going through a number of questions on the subject I am somehow not able to complete the job of posting data in the tables.

If I use normal form `submit` the data gets saved in both the tables, however while using **ajax** I keep getting `400 (Bad Request)`.

My **view** to process the **ajax** request is:

```
def ajxCreateRtp(request):
    if request.is_ajax and request.method == "POST":
        form = RtpCreateForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            formset = CreateRtpFormset()
            if formset.is_valid():
                formset_instance = formset.save()
                instance = form.save()

                ser_instance = serializers.serialize('json', [ instance, formset_instance, ])
                return JsonResponse({"instance": ser_instance}, status=200)
            else:
                return JsonResponse({"error": form.errors}, status=400)

    return JsonResponse({"error": ""}, status=400)
```

The **error** in the console reads like:

> POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/.../.../.../rtp/ajax/add/ 400 (Bad Request)
> send @ jquery-3.4.1.js:9837 ajax @ jquery-3.4.1.js:9434 (anonymous) @
> (index):1011 dispatch @ jquery-3.4.1.js:5237 elemData.handle @
> jquery-3.4.1.js:5044

**Note**: *If I remove the `.formset` parts from the view **ajxCreateRtp**, the entered data in the header form gets saved to the parent model.*

The **jQuery/Ajax** script in the template is:

```
$(function() {
    $('#rtpForm').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        // console.log(data);
        
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "{% url 'ajax_add_rtp' %}",
            data: data,
            success: function(response) {
                console.log('Data Saved');
            },
            error: function (response) {
                console.log('Problem encountered');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Could somebody get me out of this problem plase?

Comment: What's in the body of the 400 response? It looks like your form is invalid and you're returning the form's validation errors in the body of the response. Those errors should explain what's going on.

Comment: @schillingt By **body** do I understand the data contained in various tabs in **Network** of the console? Eg. General, Response Headers etc?

Comment: Yes, the Network tab in the console, then look for the request to /rtp/ajax/add, click on that and look at the request to see what was sent over the wire to the server and then the response to see what the server is responding with. The Response side is what should be including the errors.

Comment: @schillingt I m sorry. Referring to this part of the console for the first time. I can see there are sections namely **General**, **Response Headers**,  **Request Headers**, **Form Data** in the tab **Headers**. Under the **Response** tab I see an output: `{"error": ""}`. Can I copy the contents of the **General** tab in my question as an **Edit**? Thanks.

Comment: @schillingt I meant contents from the **Headers** tab.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the case of `form.is_valid() is False` is not being properly handled. Adding another return statement to include the form's errors and adjusting the other to include the formset's errors seems more appropriate. It should provide you with the information to continue debugging in the Network -> Response panel of the browser's developer tools.

```
def ajxCreateRtp(request):
    if request.is_ajax and request.method == "POST":
        form = RtpCreateForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            formset = CreateRtpFormset()
            if formset.is_valid():
                formset_instance = formset.save()
                instance = form.save()

                ser_instance = serializers.serialize('json', [ instance, formset_instance, ])
                return JsonResponse({"instance": ser_instance}, status=200)
            else:
                return JsonResponse({"error": formset.errors}, status=400)
        return JsonResponse({"error": form.errors}, status=400)

    return JsonResponse({"error": "Invalid request type."}, status=400)
```

Comment: Updated the view. Under the **Response** tab it is now showing `{"error": []}`. Also while checking the data under head **Form Data**, I find that the entries against the `id`s are **blank** (which I think should be as these are to be created as the records are saved?). Rest I can't figure out. By the way, the child model `id` is an **AutoField** (not Django created one).

Comment: On a hunch, tried to create a new record for a combination of **header fields** already created in the DB. And as it should happen, in the **Response** panel the error thrown is the `ValidationError` message: `{"error": {"rtp_material": ["Record exists for the combination of key values."]}}`. Which I think is from the `{"error": form.errors}, status=400` segment of the code. Does that mean that `formset` validation is not happening (or **is valid**)?

Comment: Change the responses in the code and see what comes out. Or you can attach a debugger and step through it manually via an IDE or using the PDB.

Comment: Just done that as suggested and guess what, the error is from the `formset` segment!!? Like I have already stated in my question I am able to save data (both models - form as well as formset data) as a normal form **submit** - so I am somehow unable to comprehend as to what is going wrong here? (*Delayed response - as SO Service went offline for maintenance*)...

Comment: I don't have enough information to answer your question(s) for you. And it's better for you to understand how to debug a django application.

Comment: Thanks. Planning to install PDB and dive deeper.