# Activate or De-Activate Status in database through Ajax-JavaScript using Django (help)

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-views

I am trying to implement a function using Ajax-JavaScript in which when I click on Activate Option, the value in database for this field changes to 'Active' and is displayed on the HTML page as active with Activate Message. If De-Activate is clicked, the text changes to De-Active along with it's value in the database and show De-Activated message

HTML page:

```
<div class="col-sm-5">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
 <div class="panel-heading">
   <h3 class="panel-title">Job activation status</h3>
 </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
      <td> Campus Name </td>
      <td> hod_name </td>
      <td>
        <select name="status" class="form-control">
            <option value="1">Active</option>
            <option value="2">Disabled</option>
        </select>
    </td>

  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

**Model:**

```
class Campus(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('Active', 'Active'),
        ('Disabled', 'Disabled'),
    )
    campus_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30)
    hod_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=25)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS, default='Disabled', blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.campus_name
```

**View:**

```
def status_update(request, pk):
    campus_status = get_object_or_404(Campus, pk=pk)
    campus_status.status = 'Active' if campus_status.status == 'Disabled' else 'Disabled'
    campus_status.save(update_fields=['status'])
    messages.success(request, '{} Status: {} successfully'.format(campus_status.campus_name, campus_status.status))
    return redirect('/dashboard/create_campus/')
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: this is procedural method I want to do it in Ajax I want to someone help me in this regards.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML page :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-sm-5">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Job activation status</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td> {{campus_name}}</td>
                    <td> {{campus_hod}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="status" id="selected_value" onchange="myFunction('{{ campus.id }}')" class="form-control">
                            <option value="1">Active</option>
                            <option value="2">Disabled</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

<script>
    function myFunction(campus_id) {
        let x = document.getElementById("selected_value").value;
        $.ajax({
            url: "/status/update/" + campus_id,
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data)
                window.location.replace("/dashboard/create_campus/");
            }

        });

    }
</script>
</html>
```

**URL.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import status_update
urlpatterns = [
    path('status/update/<str:pk>', status_update, name="status update")
]
```

**View:**

```
import json

from django.contrib import messages
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.http import JsonResponse

# Create your views here.
def status_update(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        request_data = json.loads(json.dumps(request.POST))
        campus_status = get_object_or_404(Campus, pk=pk)
        campus_status.status = 'Active' if campus_status.status == 'Disabled' else 'Disabled'
        campus_status.save()
        message = {'message': 'Status Updated Successfully', 'status': 'success'}
        messages.success(request,'{} Status: {} successfully'.format(campus_status.campus_name, campus_status.status))
        return JsonResponse(data=message, status=200, safe=False)
```

**Model:**

```
class Campus(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('Active', 'Active'),
        ('Disabled', 'Disabled'),
    )
    campus_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30)
    hod_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=25)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS, default='Disabled', blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.campus_name
```

Comment: it works but it send whole index page data, I want it update only select part of the table.

Comment: Did not get , can you please share screenshot or working code github link . Will look into that .

Comment: screenshot https://ibb.co/bLDyVPG
link is (ImgBB) website I shared

Comment: I looked into the image , nothing is cleared . What do you mean by whole index page data . Better you share github link .

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is basically an asynchronous request from client side code (i.e JavaScript) and not a Django server side feature. AJAX can be implemented in your Django application using jQuery or any other JavaScript library or framework.

Refer the below two links for how to implement AJAX in a DJANGO application

[Ajax with jQuery Django example](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html)

Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20307569/8325074) to another SO answer which has more details.

I did not modify your code to work with Ajax, I believe you can do it yourself by referring the provided links.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Thanks