# Django: How to submit the form and receive the result on the same page without reloading the page

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax, django-forms

I am working in django where I submit the input data and receive the manipulated result on the same page. Whenever I submit the form, the page reloads. I want to receive the output data, which is manipulated, on the same page without reloading / refreshing the page.

The `model.py` file is like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
# Create your models here.

class BFS(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

The `forms.py` file is like this:

```
from django import forms
from .models import BFS

class BFSForm(forms.ModelForm):
    description = forms.CharField(
                        required=False, 
                        label=False,
                        widget=forms.Textarea(
                                attrs={
                                    'id': 'TA1',
                                    'rows': '10vh',
                                    'cols': '8vw',
                                    'placeholder': 'Enter Your Map Here',
                                    'class': 'textfield-style',
                                    'style': 'max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;outline: none; border: none; background-color: white; width: 100%; padding: 12px 20px; margin: 8px 0; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 20px; spellcheck="false";',
                                }
                            )
                        )
    
    class Meta:
        model = BFS
        fields = [
            'description'
        ]
```

The `views.py` file is like this;

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from .forms import BFSForm
from .models import BFS
from .ml import Maze

# def product_create_view(request):
def bfs_view(request):
    form = BFSForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        form = BFSForm()

    try:
        image_url_info = None
        num_states_explored = None
        final_solution = None

        text_file = open("BFS\outputs\maze.txt", "w")
        field_name = 'description'
        input_value = BFS.objects.latest('id')

        field_object = BFS._meta.get_field(field_name)
        field_value = field_object.value_from_object(input_value)

        field_string_value = str(field_value).split("\n")
        text_file.writelines(field_string_value)
        text_file.close()

        m = Maze("BFS\outputs\maze.txt")
        print("Solving...")
        m.solve()
        m.output_image("static/search/bfs/maze.png", show_explored=True)

        image_url_info = "/../../../static/search/bfs/maze.png"
        num_states_explored = m.num_explored
        final_solution = str(''.join(m.end_result))

    except:
        print("BFS ERROR: Error in the try session of BFS in views.py")

    context = {
        'form': form, 'image_url': image_url_info, 'states_explored': num_states_explored, 
        'solution': final_solution
    }
    return render(request, "BFS/bfs.html", context)
```

The BFS app `urls.py` file is like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from BFS.views import bfs_view

app_name = 'BFS'

urlpatterns = [
    path('bfs/', bfs_view),
]


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

The `bfs.html` file is like this:

```
<form method='POST'>{% csrf_token %}
   {{ form.as_p }}
   <input type='submit' value='Search' class="submit-btn poppins"/></a>
</form>
```

Comment: You can use Ajax for this. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306981/how-do-i-integrate-ajax-with-django-applications

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I integrate Ajax with Django applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306981/how-do-i-integrate-ajax-with-django-applications)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot avoid reloading the page if you use a classic HTTP formular.

To achieve what you want, you need in your frontend to :

- make an AJAX call
- handle in Javascript the rerendering of your page

It can be done with VanillaJS or you can use libs to help you do it as [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) or [jquery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is Possible when you make an ajax call or by using javascript.
And after on submit ajax form you can do

```
event.preventDefault()
```